# GraphQL playground for java / Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, voyager, graphql-playground

Is there a GraphQL playground plugin available with springboot. By default graphql-spring-boot-starter gives `graphiql` UI which looks very basic.

Answer (score -1):

For **GraphQL Playground** in springboot add playground-spring-boot-starter :

Maven repo : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java-kickstart/playground-spring-boot-starter/5.10.0

Also there are few other interesting tools to checkout .

[**Alter**](https://altair.sirmuel.design/) :

Maven repo : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java-kickstart/altair-spring-boot-starter

[**Voyager**](https://apis.guru/graphql-voyager/)

Maven Repo : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java/voyager-spring-boot-autoconfigure

Comment: All these artefacts look abandoned, the last updates are several years ago.